# How can I work around a member not found error?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a command where you are supposed to have 3 options:

*1) Mention user*

*2) Enter user ID*

*3) Enter arbitrary name*

In all 3 cases the bot should spit out the embed with the appropriate input.
In doing so it should:

1. If it is a Discord user mark it in the description.
2. If it is not a user just accept the entered name but send the embed anyway with the name in the description.

**The normal way it works:**

```py
@client.command()
async def slap(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    if member is None:
        re = discord.Embed()
        re.title = "Du hast die Luft geschlagen, Idiot..."
        re.set_image(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/f9/f9/8ff9f9b0e469f751f47fc0a995a172ad.gif")
        await ctx.send(embed=re)

    else:
        er = discord.Embed()
        er.title = "Das muss weh tun..."
        er.description = f"Du hast {member.mention} geschlagen!"
        er.set_image(url=random.choice(slapgif))
        await ctx.send(embed=er)
```

But if I input a random name it gives me the `BadArgument` error. How can I avoid that and also accept random names?

**I tried:**

```py
user: str = None
```

This of course then gives only the ID when entered, but also names like `I'mTest123` which is of course desired, but the with the ID should end in a `member` if this is on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gives the error since you specified the member argument to be a discord member, changing it to this should work:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def slap(ctx, *, member=None):
       if member is None:
          re = discord.Embed()
          re.title = "Du hast die Luft geschlagen, Idiot..."
          re.set_image(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/f9/f9/8ff9f9b0e469f751f47fc0a995a172ad.gif")
          await ctx.send(embed=re)

       else:
          er = discord.Embed()
          er.title = "Das muss weh tun..."
          er.description = f"Du hast {member.mention} geschlagen!"
          er.set_image(url=random.choice(slapgif))
          await ctx.send(embed=er)
```

Also if you want it to accept random names you can use isinstance() and type() functions in an if statement like this:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def slap(ctx, *, member=None):
       if member is None:
           re = discord.Embed()
           re.title = "Du hast die Luft geschlagen, Idiot..."
           re.set_image(url="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/f9/f9/8ff9f9b0e469f751f47fc0a995a172ad.gif")
           await ctx.send(embed=re)
 
        else:
           if isinstance(member, discord.Member): #checks if it's a discord.member
              er = discord.Embed()
              er.title = "Das muss weh tun..."
              er.description = f"Du hast {member.mention} geschlagen!"
              er.set_image(url=random.choice(slapgif))
              await ctx.send(embed=er)
           elif len(member) == 18 and type(int(member)) == int: #checks if it's an user ID
              member2 = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(int(member))
              er = discord.Embed()
              er.title = "Das muss weh tun..."
              er.description = f"Du hast {member2.mention} geschlagen!"
              er.set_image(url=random.choice(slapgif))
              await ctx.send(embed=er)
           else:
              er = discord.Embed()
              er.title = "Das muss weh tun..."
              er.description = f"Du hast {member} geschlagen!"
              er.set_image(url=random.choice(slapgif))
              await ctx.send(embed=er)
```